# Moving Java Object using UFT and VBScript

Tags: java, vbscript, hp-uft

Hopefully I am not repeating a question but I have searched and found very little related to what I need to know. I have seen some places where similar situations are a resounding not possible but I have to make absolutely sure before I give up on doing this if it has anyway.

So I currently work with a Java based desktop application that uses a graphical interface of text fields, grids, and buttons. Only recently has a new ambitious portion of the product been introduced with drag and drop features so that an "Icon" representing a request can be drug to be associated with the provisioned order in another grid . In the background the code is making status changes to the request with SQL so I can and will create tests for making database changes directly. However to help ensure that the graphical interface acts like it should I want to use VBScript in UFT to automate creating requests and then associate the order by moving or "dragging" the icon.

So any suggestions how I would best get this done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question is far too broad to be able to give you a useful answer.  Please narrow down your question to the specific issue you're facing.

Comment: If all you want to do is drag something in `uft` you can use the `drag` and `drop` methods to achieve this.